# Python POST request (web scraping)

Tags: python, post, screen-scraping

I can not make a post request with these parameters:

Site: www.zoover.it

This is my code:

```
import requests

Request_URL="http://www.zoover.it/services/Testimonials/TestimonialQueryService.asmx/AccommodationTestimonialQuery"
serviceRequest:{"CurrentLanguage":"Language_NL","PartyFilter":"","CurrentPage":"0","PageSize":"10","SortOption":"date-of-visit"}
pageContext:{"EntityLevel":"accommodation","NewEntityLevel":"accommodation","EntityId":151433,"EntityName":"Residence Belmonte Vacanze****","SemanticName":"accommodation-testimonials","PhysicalUrl":"/accommodation/testimonials.aspx","CurrentSiteVariation":"it","CmsAccommodationTypeFilter":"","PageCode":"accommodation","PageSubcode":"testimonials","CmsEntity":{"Level":1,"Id":151433},"NewCmsEntity":{"Level":{"EntityLevel":"accommodation"},"Id":151433},"Path":"/accommodation/testimonials.aspx","PageSemantic":{"SemanticName":"accommodation-testimonials","PhysicalUrl":"/accommodation/testimonials.aspx","KnownFriendlyParams":["accommodationId"],"HasFriendlyUrl":true},"EntityType":"Appartamento","PageRequestUrl":"/italia/toscana/montaione/residence-belmonte-vacanze/appartamento"}

r = requests.post(Request_URL, params=serviceRequest)

print r.text
```

I have two problems:

1) in R.TEXT I always get "HTTP Error 411. The request must be chunked or have a content length."
2) I don't know how to do POST with two dictionaries (serviceRequest and pageContext)

My goal is to make web scraping by changing the parameters of the dictionary.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `data` keyword instead and the content length will be set automatically:

```
r = requests.post(Request_URL, data=serviceRequest)
```

You'll have to combine the two dictionaries into one:

```
data = serviceRequest.copy()
data.update(pageContext)
r = requests.post(Request_URL, data=data)
```

Comment: I think the important point here is that using `data` will actually process the data for posting, while params will just amend the request URL

Comment: I tried it and R.TEXT now is: "Index was outside the bounds of the array.". Better than before ... :) What could it be?

Comment: @RoverDar: That is an error from the webserver, no idea what that site does or expects.

Comment: I found serviceRequest and pageContext with Chrome Developer Tools (network section). The value is the same. What could be changed?

Comment: @RoverDar: Are those perhaps JSON values instead of python dictionaries? I have no idea what the API does or how things are posted to it.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters: Perhaps they could be json values​​. I do not know, I'm studying the operation of the site just now. What would change if they json values?

Comment: @RoverDar: You'd encode the whole dict with `data = json.dumps({serviceRequest=serviceRequest, pageContext=pageContext)` perhaps. Impossible to tell without seeing the request-response details. You'd need to set a content-type header too, I guess. Most of all *I can only guess*.

Comment: if I do data = json.dumps({serviceRequest=serviceRequest, pageContext=pageContext}) I have "SyntaxError: invalid syntax" in = (serviceRequest=serviceRequest)...

Comment: @Martijn Pieters: I get the same error: "Index was outside the bounds of the array"... I will try other methods. Thanks for your help

Comment: Now I have **<Response [401]>**. Could be a problem of cookies? How can I manage it?

Comment: @RoverDar: This is going way beyond what we can help you with; it's simply too localized. 401 does mean unauthorized, no idea how that site checks for authorization. Cookies is one option.